# Get Facebook identity of user visiting my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

I have a website where users can sign up using Facebook. I then have access to their friends' IDs and names.

If a new user visits the page, someone who has NOT signed up via Facebook, is it possible for me to display a list of signed-up users who have him as their friend? It seems that I should not be able to, but I recall seeing this on other sites: I never sign up using Facebook, but sites never-the-less seem to know my Facebook identity.

I guess it's like Facepile https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/, but I need to be able to customize this list and get at the IDs and names of the friends.

Comment: No, you will know _nothing_ about a user visiting your site before they have authorized your app – for a good reason called “privacy”.

Comment: But sites are able to show me which of my friends have signed up even though I haven't signed up myself. I guess this is just Facebook knowing it and showing it in an iframe, which the site itself can't access?

Comment: Yes, the social plugins run outside of the context of the page embedding them – the data comes from Facebook’s servers directly, and those are able to recognize a user by the cookies set under their domain. But the embedding site gets none of that info.